# Shairport on-start command with multiple words

Tags: bash

I'm trying to set up Shairport to run a script when a user connects and an other one when the user disconnects again.

I tried adding the on-start and on-stop arguments. This works fine when starting Shairport manually.

But I don't know how to add this arguments in the /etc/init.d/shairport.

I tried:

```
START="python script1.py"
STOP="python script2.py"
DAEMON_ARGS="--daemon --pidfile $PIDFILE --log $LOGFILE --on-start=\"$START\" --on-stop \"$STOP\""
```

But this results in an error message saying:

> Invalid audio argument: script1.py"

I think the problem is that the command consists of two words but I don't know how to solve the problem.

Could you please help me?

Comment: I don't know shairpoint but have you tried making script1.py executable (in a dir listed in $PATH) and simply writing START="script1.py"?

Comment: @ShellFish Thanks for this tip, but I can't start python scripts like this. But you gave me the idea to implement my script as a bash script and this works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, that's great news. Glad to have been of service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in fact run a python/python3 script by executing the file. Just make sure to include a hashbang, here's an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

print "hello"
```

Then you could do:

```
$ chmod u+x script1.py
$ script1.py
hello
```

But only as long as the script is located in a directory listed in `$PATH`. Note that the path to python (or python3 if you prefer that) is not necessarily `/usr/bin/python`, you can easily find out the location using `$ which python` though.

I know you fixed it by encapsulating the execution in a shell script but this seems a little cleaner in my opinion.

Edit:

**A more detailed note on the `PATH` variable.**

When executing a script in a shell, your shell will look for the command/script in directories listed in this variable. As long as the script is located in one of these directories, your shell will know how to call the script (internally it will call it using ./script_name, which is how you can call any script too). A sample output:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Note that the directory containing python is also listed in the output above (`/use/bin`), so you can call `python` as a command.

When you create a script and make it executable you can call it using `$ ./myscript`, if it were to be located in `/sbin` for example you could call it using simply `$ myscript`.

**How to add a directory to PATH**

You can extend the directory list in PATH using a simple `$ PATH="$PATH:/path/to/new/dir"` command but this is not ideal because you'd have to do it every time you open a shell. The appropriate way to do it is by adding a line to your .bashrc file (this is a file that executes every line at the beginning of each shell session). **Caution**: if this file is faulty you could end up not being able to access your shell at all, be sure to back it up before testing out the new content.

The best approach in my opinion is to make a directory containing all user made scripts (mine is called ~/bin). That being said, you can follow these guidelines:

```
mkdir ~/bin   # create the custom script dir
mv script1.py ~/bin   # move your script to the dir
chmod u+x ~/bin/script1.py   # make file executable
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc_bak   # backup file (to be safe)
vim +$ ~/.bashrc   # open bashrc file at the last line
```

Now in vim (or an editor of choice) add this line to the file: `export PATH=$PATH:~/bin` and save (only adding this line will never damage the bashrc file).

You can now call any executable script located in your ~/bin directory!

An even better approach is to create a new file .bashrc_custom and include it in the original ./bashrc file but that's not necessary and will make things more complicated I believe.

Start a new shell and test it out, your output should now be like this:

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/home/user/bin
```

If this is the case and everything works, remove the backup `rm -f ~/.bashrc_bak`

Note that you can use bashrc to tweak your command line, you can set up a custom command line prompt or insert certain aliases. Mine for example contains some aliases:

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
export WORKBENCH="/home/user/my/current/project"
alias clone="gnome-terminal ."
alias explore="gnome-open ."
alias pdf="gnome-open *.pdf"
alias bashrc="vim +$ ~/.bashrc"
alias wb="cd $WORKBENCH"
alias ff="firefox >/dev/null 2>&1 "
```

Hope this helps, ask questions if something is unclear.

Comment: You're right this seems to be a cleaner opinion and I'm able to start the shell script but it doesn't work so far. Maybe python would be the easier way. I just had to change your command `script1.py` to `./script1.py`
Just in case anybody else has this problem. :)

Comment: Do echo $PATH, you'll see a list of directories separated by ':'. These are the directories in which your shell will search for executables. By calling '$ python script.py' your shell will look for the script/command python in the directories listed in PATH. I will expand my answer in a second so it becomes clear!